# Protecting questions from mobile site

Tags: discussion, mobile-web, protected-questions, mobile-app

I’ve searched through blog posts and questions just about everywhere I know to look on Google and SE (which is still far from everywhere there is to look, mind), but I cannot find anyone mentioning this at all, which surprises me, because it seems like such an obvious question that I had expected to be drowned in duplicates.

Why exactly is it that the *Protect* link that appears next to the *Close* and *Flag* links on sites where you have more than 15,000 rep is not there when viewing the site from a mobile browser (i.e., mobile web browser view) and from the StackExchange mobile app (at least on iOS)?

Is it deliberate? And if so, what is the reasoning behind not allowing high-rep users to protect questions from their mobile devices?

*(Edited to specify user interface and also to bump, since the question has had no response after Anna Lear’s comment a week ago.)*

Comment: Are you talking about mobile apps or the mobile web browser view?

Comment: @AnnaLear Mainly the mobile web browser view, though I have wondered why it's not there in the (iOS) mobile app, too. The app is sufficiently different in general from the web version layout that it's less ‘unexpected’ there.

Comment: I'd hazard the guess (albeit fairly confidently) that there is no [API method](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) to protect questions.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I take it that would explain why there's no _Protect_ option in the app—but the mobile web browser view shouldn't be affected by this, should it?

Comment: I've been wanting to ask the same, but I think it would be closed as a duplicate of this. This needs more attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hadn’t noticed before, but this appears to have been fixed at some point, probably as part of the new and (mostly) improved layout. The protect option is now available in the mobile view as well.